# MY SQL trying to use transactions and locking

Tags: mysql

how to write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named test. The procedure two SQL statements coded as a transaction to delete the row with a customer ID of 8 from the Customers table. and delete all addresses for that customer from the Addresses table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are actually looking for a simple [MySQL foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), with the `ON DELETE` clause.

Using a foreign key is the proper way to represent the relation within your data, and also provides built-in solutions to manage child  records when parent are modified or deleted. You seem to be looking for the `CASCADE` option:

> `CASCADE`: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` are supported.

Sample schema that demonstrates the foreign key syntax:

```
create table customers (customer_id int primary key);

create table addresses(
  address_id int primary key,
  customer_id int,
  foreign key (customer_id) 
      references customers(customer_id)
      on delete cascade
      on update cascade
);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into customers(customer_id) values
    (1),
    (2);

insert into addresses(address_id, customer_id) values
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2);
```

Customer `1` has 2 adresses. Now let's delete that customer.

```
delete from customers where customer_id = 1;
```

Rows were automatically removed from the child table:

```
select * from addresses;

| address_id | customer_id |
| ---------- | ----------- |
| 3          | 2           |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eVZ27xjGVVje5vBMUtrWqG/1)**.